# Excel VBA date changes automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have this strange problem. When I use this function

```
Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(2, 8).Value = ComboBox2.Value
```

Where my **ComboBox2.Value = 02/01/2019** I got the following output in Cells(2,8) --> **01/02/2019**

But in my cell properties I have already set that I want "dd/mm/yyyy"

Where is the problem?

Comment: Probably in your Regional settings in your computer system, got some issues with that.

Comment: Does using `.Value2` change anything?

Comment: @M.Schalk No it doesn't change anything

Comment: @SometingNew Keep `ComboBox2.Value` as it is, use `.Value2` for the cell

Comment: how do you set the combobox values?

Comment: You can also try `Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(2, 8).Text` instead. This might help your cause.

Comment: @Dean it gives me error: Impossibile set "Text" for the property Range

Comment: @SNicolaou I fill it from an array, but when filling it I already give him a format 
```arr(i)= Format(myDay + i, "dd/mm/yyyy")```

Comment: You could try something like this: `Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(2, 8).Value = CStr(ComboBox2.Value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would convert to a date the combobox value. tried (replicated) your issue and this fix worked for me. basically, use CDate to set the cell value.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

  Dim v As Variant
  Dim d As Date

  v = Me.ComboBox1.Value
  d = CDate(v)

  Sheet3.Range("A1").Value = d

End Sub
```

Comment: obviously, change/rename accordingly :-)